# Remove last digit in a string in Java only if it is just one digit present

Tags: java, regex

I would like to remove last digit in a Java string, only if it is just one digit present.

E.g.

```
String text = "I am the9 number1"; // should be "I am the number"
```

Cases where it should do nothing:

```
String = "I913 am the55 number11"; // Should remain the same.
```

I tried this without success:

```
String text = "I am the1 number1";
text = text.replaceAll("^[0-9]$", "");
```

Didnt work. Any help?

Comment: does it have to be one number in all string? for example, should `I am the 2 number 1` remains the same?

Comment: It has to be a number at the end of any string. Like ```I am number1 1 and you number2 2``` Should become ```I am number 1 and you number 2```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To replace the last digit in a string you may use

```
text = text.replaceAll("\\B(?<!\\d)\\d\\b", "");
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/D3y94p/3).

**Details**

- `\B` - a letter or `_` must appear immediately to the left of the current position
- `(?<!\d)` - a negative lookbehind that fails the match if there is a digit immediately to the left of the current location
- `\d` - a digit
- `\b` - a word boundary.

[Java demo](https://ideone.com/MXtKFO):

```
String rx = "\\B(?<!\\d)\\d\\b";
System.out.println("I am the number1".replaceAll(rx, ""));
// => I am the number
System.out.println("I am the number11".replaceAll(rx, "")); 
// => I am the number11
System.out.println("I am 4the number1 @#@%$grtuy".replaceAll(rx, "")); 
// => I am 4the number @#@%$grtuy
System.out.println("I am number1 1 and you number2 2".replaceAll(rx, ""));
// => I am number 1 and you number 2
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. Is there a way to use it together with replaceAll instead of replaceFirst?

Comment: Thanks. Taking this as answer as I made a mistake in the wording.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

`(?<=[A-Za-z])\d(?!\d)`

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/GH4SQK/1/)

**Details**

`(?<=[A-Za-z])`: it indicates word character before digit as positive lookbehind

`\d`: indicates number

`(?!\d)`: there has to be no other number after matched number (negative lookahead)

**Sample Code**

`text = text.replaceAll("(?<=[A-Za-z])\d(?!\d)", "");`

Comment: This is actually what I wanted as it works better for any string position, not just in the end. Thank you.

Comment: @tavalendo You did not mention you want to match anywhere inside a string. Also, if you really mean *last* and not *at the end of string*, you need `(?!.*\d)` at the end of the pattern, not `(?!\d)`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew sorry about that. I fixed the wording in tbe description.